# My google map Android App does Not Run on Samsung Mobiles however its running on Other mobiles Brands

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, import

This my code `MapsActivity.java` file please see 
my code is not running in samsung mobile but run in all mobiles . I am confused what should i do with code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    public void onSearch(View view) {
        EditText location_tf = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFaddress);
        String location = location_tf.getText().toString();
        List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;
        if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {
                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker"));


            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        }
    }


    public void changeType(View view) {
        if (mMap.getMapType() == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL) {
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        } else
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        double longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)      
            .zoom(12)               
            .build();                  
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!").snippet("Consider yourself located"));

    }

}
```

My google map Android App does Not Run on Samsung Mobiles however its running on Other mobiles Brands. What is the problem?

This is the logcat error:

```
04-16 12:33:51.098 10800-10800/intracode.org.contactmanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: intracode.org.contactmanager, PID: 10800
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{intracode.org.contactmanager/intracode.org.contactmanager.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at intracode.org.contactmanager.MapsActivity.setUpMap(MapsActivity.java:109)
  at intracode.org.contactmanager.MapsActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(MapsActivity.java:72)
  at intracode.org.contactmanager.MapsActivity.onCreate(MapsActivity.java:48)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post your logcat error?

Comment: What s the line 109 of `MapsActivity`?

Comment: @antonio can you please help me ?

Comment: I need to know what's line 109

Comment: line 109 is code of normal view of google maps.        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

Comment: `mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);`can't throw NPE because you have already used the `mMap` instance earlier in that method, but the next line `double latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();` can throw NPE if `myLocation` is `null`

Comment: ok thanks i will try and than notify you....... thanks for help